# Gradle system error "java.net.BindException: Address already in use" after first build

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

This is a typical scenario of "one day you woke up and realised things that used to work stopped working for unknown reason."

I have a Jenkins job that run Gradle command. Now, after a successful build, the following will throw exceptions below.

```
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
03:38:49.137 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain - Assuming the daemon was started with following jvm opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=512m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx2048m, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]
03:38:49.501 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.server.DaemonServices - Creating daemon context with opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=512m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx2048m, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]
03:38:49.563 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] start() called on daemon - DefaultDaemonContext[uid=57b530d9-9776-4ea2-8432-fa1663ef1e7e,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64,daemonRegistryDir=/vol/jenkins/.gradle/daemon,pid=15417,idleTimeout=120000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx2048m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
03:38:49.575 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] updating lastActivityAt to 1431574729575
03:38:49.585 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface eth0
03:38:49.585 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
03:38:49.586 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
03:38:49.586 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:2000:bff:fe2b:82c6%2
03:38:49.587 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /10.147.28.2
03:38:49.588 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote multicast interface eth0
03:38:49.589 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface lo
03:38:49.589 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? true
03:38:49.590 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? false
03:38:49.590 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback address /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1
03:38:49.591 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback address /127.0.0.1
03:38:49.602 [ERROR] [system.err] 
03:38:49.603 [ERROR] [system.err] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
03:38:49.604 [ERROR] [system.err] 
03:38:49.604 [ERROR] [system.err] * What went wrong:
03:38:49.605 [ERROR] [system.err] java.net.BindException: Address already in use
03:38:49.605 [ERROR] [system.err] 
03:38:49.606 [ERROR] [system.err] * Try:
03:38:49.606 [ERROR] [system.err] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
03:38:49.610 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Removing daemon address: null
03:38:49.622 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
03:38:49.626 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
03:38:49.644 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.


* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
03:38:49.137 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain - Assuming the daemon was started with following jvm opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=512m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx2048m, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]
03:38:49.501 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.server.DaemonServices - Creating daemon context with opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=512m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx2048m, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]
03:38:49.563 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] start() called on daemon - DefaultDaemonContext[uid=57b530d9-9776-4ea2-8432-fa1663ef1e7e,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64,daemonRegistryDir=/vol/jenkins/.gradle/daemon,pid=15417,idleTimeout=120000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx2048m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
03:38:49.575 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] updating lastActivityAt to 1431574729575
03:38:49.585 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface eth0
03:38:49.585 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
03:38:49.586 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
03:38:49.586 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:2000:bff:fe2b:82c6%2
03:38:49.587 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /10.147.28.2
03:38:49.588 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote multicast interface eth0
03:38:49.589 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface lo
03:38:49.589 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? true
03:38:49.590 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? false
03:38:49.590 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback address /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1
03:38:49.591 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback address /127.0.0.1
03:38:49.602 [ERROR] [system.err] 
03:38:49.603 [ERROR] [system.err] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
03:38:49.604 [ERROR] [system.err] 
03:38:49.604 [ERROR] [system.err] * What went wrong:
03:38:49.605 [ERROR] [system.err] java.net.BindException: Address already in use
03:38:49.605 [ERROR] [system.err] 
03:38:49.606 [ERROR] [system.err] * Try:
03:38:49.606 [ERROR] [system.err] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
03:38:49.610 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Removing daemon address: null
03:38:49.622 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
03:38:49.626 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
03:38:49.644 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.

    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:112)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:105)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.SingleUseDaemonClient.execute(SingleUseDaemonClient.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.SingleUseDaemonClient.execute(SingleUseDaemonClient.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the decription and stack trace you have given, gradle is trying to start the daemon from within the job configuration and not shutting it down at the end. This means that the next time you try and run the job, it can't start the daemon because the daemon is already running (and thus failing the build)

Consider taking the daemon out of the job configuration and running it as a separate process (see https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html)

Alternatively, either add a conditional check to start the daemon only if it isn't already running or shut down the daemon at the end of the build (not recommended)

Comment: Actually, looking through the documentation for Gradle daemon, it's not recommended for CI environments so maybe just turn it off all together.

Comment: thanks for the reply. 1) the daemon is actually teared down after the job finished. it's just not showing in the logs because that was second job that failed. 2) I tried to put ```org.gradle.daemon=false``` in my gradle.properties but still the error showed

Comment: Have you checked the process list to see if the daemon is still running? If it is, kill it before triggering any jobs

Comment: I tried ``./gradlew --stop`` it told me there is no Daemon running at all. funny thing is, even if I run ``./gradlew clean --no-daemon``` it still shows error Unable to start the daemon process.

Comment: how should I check process list to verify daemon is running?

Comment: You can check this with `ps aux | grep -v grep | grep gradle-launcher`. The launcher might be running as a different user.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I fixed it by change -XX:MaxPermSize to default 256m. It was set 512m. Do you have any idea why this size change works? It seems irrelevant to the error message

Comment: Absolutely no idea but if I was to hazard a guess, by lowering the MaxPermSize you've prevented the daemon from being able to start and therefore it's carrying on as if no daemon is required.